# Does adding a NSMutableDictionary to a NSMutableDictionary make a copy or does it keep a pointer

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

Does adding a NSMutableDictionary to a NSMutableDictionary make a copy or does it keep a pointer.

I want to be able to update the content of the first NSMutableDictionary and have that tracked within the other NSMutableDictionary - for example...

```
    NSMutableDictionary* dictA = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary* dictB = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictA setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1 ] forKey:@"number"];
    [dictB setValue:dictA forKey:@"dictA"];

    [dictA setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2 ] forKey:@"number"];
```

Will dictB.dictA.number now = 2?

Comment: Well, I can think of one very good way to find out. Try it.

Comment: It keeps the pointer.  Modifying the inner dictionary will result in modifications visible via the outer dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will. In general, Cocoa collection classes only retain the objects added to them (the purpose: this way you can insert non-copyable objects too).

(With CoreFoundation trickery and toll-free bridging, it is possible to realize an `NSArray` that copies its elements, though.)

Comment: The main reason for not always copying is that it would be incredibly inefficient, in time and space, to do so.

Comment: @HotLicks that's another good reason too but I don't think it's worth arguing about which reason is more important. For example, copying an `NSNumber` stored in a tagged pointer is just a single `MOV` (or whatever) instruction.

Comment: NSNumber objects are immutable and never need to be copied.  They're also incredibly small.  An NSMutableDictionary, by comparison, is huge, and if every reference to one made a copy the copies would quickly consume all of storage.